# Encoding URL Query String Value from JavaScript to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that uses ASP.NET MVC and JavaScript. I am generating a URL in my JavaScript like this:

```
// Imagine 'filter' is "AT&T".
var v = filter.replace(/'/g, "''");
v = v.replace(/&/g, "%26%");
var t = "(clause eq '" + v + "')";

// At this point, t is "(clause eq 'AT%26%T')"
window.location = '@Url.Content("~/find?")' + 'q=' + t;
```

In my ASP.NET MVC controller action, I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Find(int? id, string q)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the `Find` action, I notice that `q` is the following:

```
(clause  eq 'AT&%T')
```

I'm not sure why. I need it to be `(clause eq 'AT%26%T')`. What am I doing wrong? I understand its some encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that your encoded ampersand `%26` is UrlDecoded serverside back to `&`. If you want to keep the url encoded version you need to escape the percent sign `%` too with its encoded equivalent `%25`:

```
v = v.replace(/&/g, "%2526%");
```